# Tauri frontend server not starting

Tags: rust, tauri

I've been using Tauri for a personal project recently, I am working on the project on two different computers, since I try to work on it on my spare time from my laptop if I am outside, and from my desktop when I am home. I cloned the git repo from my laptop and it worked perfectly, but if I try to run it again from my desktop (after pulling the project updates) this happens:

[image: Error]

If I try to run the project from my laptop it still works, no changes on the code or anything, I checked and the port is not being used.

The command I am using to run the project is the one provided in the website:

```
npm run tauri dev
```

Does anyone know why is this happening or how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this very same issue.

It turned out that the "devPath" in tauri.conf.json doesn't match what the npm run actually gave me. The complete output message looks like this:

```
  VITE v4.1.4  ready in 682 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
        Warn Waiting for your frontend dev server to start on http://127.0.0.1:5173/...
        Warn Waiting for your frontend dev server to start on http://127.0.0.1:5173/...
        Warn Waiting for your frontend dev server to start on http://127.0.0.1:5173/...
```

In my case, the local server is localhost but tauri is expecting 127.0.0.1

To solve this, edit tauri.conf.json:

```
  "build": {
    "beforeBuildCommand": "npm run build",
    "beforeDevCommand": "npm run dev",
    "devPath": "http://127.0.0.1:5173", // change to http://localhost:5173
    "distDir": "../build"
  },
```

Comment: For me, following the Vite guide on the Tauri site, I had to change `"http://localhost:1420"` to `"http://localhost:5173"`. Also it didn't like comments in the tauri config JSON file.